# How to output last match in multiple files in subdirectories and output the file path with each match

Tags: find

I've managed to find the last match in multiple files in multiple subdirectories, but I wish to also output the file path and cannot manage to. How can I change

```
find subdirprefix* -name log -exec sh -c "tac '{}' | grep -m1 'search string' " \;
```

Such that it outputs both the last match in each file and the filepath (relative to the starting directory, not the full path)

i.e. the output should be along the lines of

```
[..]search string[..] : subdirprefix1/log
[..]search string[..] : subdirprefix2/log
[..]search string[..] : subdirprefix3/log
```

Comment: Is it essential for the filepath to be output *after* the match? `grep` already has a `-H` option for outputting the filename before (although your command will need to be modified a little to take advantage of it, since right now you're grepping stdin)

Comment: Hi @steeldriver , no it isn't essential for the filepath output to be after, I've tried the -H option before but as you say since I am grepping stdin the only output I get is (standard input): [..] search string [..], and I am unsure how to fix this

Comment: What OS and/or grep implementation (GNU or something else) are you using?

Comment: @steeldriver grep (GNU grep) 3.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least with GNU grep, you can use `-H` to label outputs with the originating filename; the trick to making this work when the input is piped via stdin is to use the `--label` option.

So for example

```
find subdirprefix* -name log -exec sh -c '
  tac "$1" | grep -H --label="$1" -m1 "search string"
' find-sh {} \;
```

or (slightly more efficiently)

```
find subdirprefix* -name log -exec sh -c '
  for f; do tac "$f" | grep -H --label="$f" -m1 "search string"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

(I took the liberty of moving `'{}'` outside of the shell scriptlet and passing it as a positional parameter instead.)

Comment: Thank you very much this works perfectly